# How to 'join' a many-to-many 2 list of related Models

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have 2 models Product and Categories, with a many-to-many relation from Product to Category.

I have a list of `Product` objects and a list of `Product` ids.

Using the Product list ids, I get categories:

```
categories = Category.objects.filter(products__in=products_list)
```

Now I want to joint the products list and the categories, similar to a `Prefetch`, but I don't have a `Queryset` but a list of Product Objects.

```
for product in products # the list with Product objects
  for category in categories:
   if ...
    ph.category = category
```

Being a many to many the relations are in the intermediary table, so I don't know how to access, not to do a new query for every category.

I'm thinking on somehow passing the "product_id" from intermediary table to category, in the `Queryset.`

Also I need only the first `Category` of each `Product`, not all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you convert your product list into a queryset, and then use [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related):

```
product_ids = [p.pk for p in products]
product_qs = Product.objects.filter(pk__in=product_ids).select_related('categories')

for product in product_qs:
    product.categories.all() # This will be prefetched.
```

Comment: doesn't call the database, when you convert in a QuerySet ?

Comment: It does - but surely you need to query the database at least once to get the additional data you need?